# Create optional one to one relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a 1:1 optional relationship between two models in Rails. The problem is as follows.

I have two models called X and Y. I need to have a 1:1 relationship between these models. I need to add the foreign key to the X model. When the Y model entry is deleted corresponding reference in X should be `NULL`. X entry can stay with or without a Y model entry. The same goes for the Y model as well.

I tried following.

Added this in the Y model.

```
belongs_to :x, optional: true
```

Added this in the X model.

```
has_one :y, dependent: :nullify
```

But this one creates a strong relationship and it looks for a referenced X entry when the Y entry is deleted.

my migration is like this.

```
add_belongs_to :x, :y, type: :uuid,
```

the primary key in the X table is `bigInt` and for the Y table it is `uuid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the associations backwards. This is a classic misconception about how belongs_to/has_one associations work in Rails.

`belongs_to` means that there is a foreign key column on *this* models table that points to the other models table. If you have:

```
class Y
  belongs_to :x, optional: true
end
```

That means that the `y.x_id` column references `x.id`. While `has_one` means that the foreign key column is on the *other* models table.

If you want to have the column defintion that you have outlined in thr question you need to flip the assocations:

```
class Y
  has_one :x, dependent: :nullify 
end

class X
  # ys.x_id column references xs.id
  belongs_to :y, optional: true
end
```

If you want the assocation to be optional you also need to make the database column nullable - the default is false for [add_reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference). You can either do that by rolling back the migration and changing it to:

```
add_belongs_to :x, :y, type: :uuid, null: true
```

Or by using:

```
change_column_null(:x, :y, true)
```

In a new migration.